# Проблема с перезаписью файлов при повторном открытии приложения (python)

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Недавно я создал небольшой проект на Python и решил  скомпилировать его в один .exe файл (с картинками, звуком и т.д...). И у меня получилось это сделать, однако возникла проблема при перезаписи файлов в приложении при повторном запуске. То есть, когда я запускаю приложение и каким-то образом там производятся изменения, файл перезаписывается, и я могу наблюдать эти изменения, но при закрытии приложения, все изменения изчезнают. Как сделать, чтобы все изменения сохранялись, даже после закрытия приложения?

Проблема решена, вот ссылка на исходник: https://github.com/mygazztop/FastNumbers/blob/master/results/FastNumbers(beta).exe

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш небольшой проект.

Comment: Может быть когда-нибудь я сделаю это, но вряд ли это будет в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы называете компиляцией - это просто процесс создания самораспаковывающегося архива, включающего интерпретатор Python, набор необходимых библиотек и файлы вашего проекта. В момент запуска весь этот хлам распаковывается во временный каталог и запускается оттуда. После завершения работы временный каталог удаляется. Если вы пытаетесь редактировать упакованные файлы, то при каждом запуске вы работаете с новой копией, что очевидно бесполезно.

Вам нужно создать или скопировать необходимый файл в какой-нибудь постоянный каталог. Например в каталог профиля пользователя или каталог в котором расположен исполняемый файл программы.

Comment: Хорошая идея, я и сам думал так сделать, но если я буду создавать файл в постоянном каталоге человека, который скачал приложение, то это вызовет ряд проблем. Например, я понятия не имею, куда складывать этот файл. А если ползователь, подумает, что этот файл представляет какую-то угрозу и удалит его, может быть случайно? Если нельзя изменять само приложение, предложите способ сохранения файла, описанный вами.

Comment: Пользователи обычно даже не заходят в AppData, не говоря уж об удалении оттуда чего-либо. Туда и сохраняйте. Или используйте реестр, если структура данных это позволяет.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал с точностью, как вы сказали. Ссылку на проект поставил в текст вопроса.